# Web server information of list of domains

Tags: http, web, http-headers

Is there any way to find web server information for all of a list of domains at once?

Example: I have many websites, and I want the info of their servers like

```
domain1.com serverinfo = apache
domain2.com serverinfo = win32
```

Perhaps something to check http headers in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

This tool can do that [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html)

Comment: good tool.. but it scan all the possible links from website, that's take time, i just want to get server info.. is this can scan single url of web page ? i tried to change options but it's just scaning all the urls of website

Comment: I never used it before, but the web site says that it can retrieve server information. So keep playing with it :)